# How To Connect micro atm device in Android/Flutter App for Matm2 Integration

Tags: android, flutter, matmul

I am currently working on integrating MATM (Micro Atm) into my Android application, and I'm seeking guidance from those who have experience with this integration.

Has anyone successfully integrated MATM into an Android app before? If so, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share your insights, tips, or any challenges you encountered during the integration process. Additionally, if there are specific code snippets or resources you found helpful, please feel free to share them.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.56'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

I am currently working on integrating MATM (Micro Atm) into my Android application, and I'm seeking guidance from those who have experience with this integration.